# Problem using viewFields to return more fields

Tags: web-services, caml-query

Do I have to put a prefix of ows before retrieving fields? because I am trying to obtain additional fields and not being able to?

```
 soapEnv += "<listName>My SP List</listName>";
    soapEnv += "<query><Query><OrderBy Override='TRUE'><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query></query>";
    soapEnv += "<viewFields><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='MyDescription'/><FieldRef Name='MyURL'/><FieldRef Name='ows_FileLeafRef'/></ViewFields></viewFields><rowLimit></rowLimit>";
    soapEnv += "</GetListItems></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answers, you need the StaticName or Internal Name (Microsoft uses both terms in different places) rather than the DisplayName when you specify column names in your Web Services calls.

The other important point is that what you get back is preceded by "ows_". So if you ask for "Title", what you get back in the XML is "ows_Title".

Comment: Long time no see... I did use both with or without ows_ but not being successful.

Comment: Okay in the soap I am using internal name and in the java I am using with the prefix and now seems to be resolving. However, myLink gives me this http://www.abc.com,%20abc%20news%20link/ instead of just the link.

Comment: @SPEveryone:  myLink was a hyperlink type field in SP. I deleted this and added a single line text field. Now it's all working.

Comment: Yes, hyperlink columns store both the text and the URL, which is what you want, really. You simply parse them apart to get whichever piece you need.

Comment: Thanks! And why some fields doesn't return at all? For example 'ContentTypeId' adds additional field to z:row, but '_HasCopyDestinations' doesn't.

Comment: Not all columns are returned by default. If you don't specify anything, you get the columns in the default view. If you want to override that, set the ViewFields in your CAML.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the ows_, but you do need to use the internal name, which is not necessarily the same as the display name. To determine the internal name go to the List Settings page for your list and click on the columns you are interested in. Look at the url in the address bar and find the Field parameter in the query string. It may be something like My_x0020_Field.

Comment: My fields are simple and I am using internal name. For example, NewsLink is NewsLink and so forth. I am getting undefined.

Comment: soapEnv += "<listName>My List</listName>";
    soapEnv += "<query><Query><OrderBy Override='TRUE'><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query></query>";
    soapEnv += "<viewFields><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='ows_FileLeafRef'/><FieldRef Name='NewsLink'/><FieldRef Name='Description'/></ViewFields></viewFields><rowLimit></rowLimit>";
    soapEnv += "</GetListItems></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";

Answer (score 0):

Each `FieldRef` within `ViewFields` corresponds to a field to be returned in the query.

Here's a code sample - It will return the Title, Active, Description, and MyLink fields where the Title field equals "Title Value":

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.ViewFields = @"<FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='Active'/><FieldRef Name='Description'/><FieldRef Name='MyLink'/>";
query.Query = 
@"
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
        <Value Type='Text'>Title Value</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>";

SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists.TryGetList("My SP List");
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
```

**I see you've changed your original question**

I think you may have some formatting issues with your XML. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923209/caml-query-to-a-sharepoint-list-order-by-a-lookup-field) question for some additional help.

Comment: excellent. however, this is in java using soap envelope.

Comment: Ok, I was unsure based on the limited results. To answer your original question, yes, each <FieldRef> within <ViewFields> corresponds to each column that is returned.

Comment: @It seems I cant get hold off myLink aka myURL and descriptin field